# How can I count and print only once?

Tags: java

My file has 6 rows of integers

For example my file name is abc.txt it has following input

```
12 13
13 1000
12 -58
8 4
```

I added the inputs like this `12+13`, `13+1000` etc etc and took average of them

I want to count and print how many times the average was inside 0-10 that is more than 0 and less than10

From my example it should print more than 0 and less than 10 = 2

I intiated `count = 0` at the beginning and run this code

```
if(avg >=0 && avg<10){
    count++;
    System.out.println ("more than 0 and less than 10 = "+count);
}
```

But it prints

```
more than 0 and less than 10 = 1
more than 0 and less than 10 = 2
```

How can I make it prints once so that the output will only be like

```
more than 0 and less than 10 = 2
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply put the `System.out.println ....` line after the loop, at the end?

Comment: avg >= 0 doesn't satisfy "more than 0" considering avg could equal 0 and still be `true` for the condiction

Comment: +1 for diligent adherence to recommendations for well-written questions.

Comment: Please show a complete example. In particular, is this `if` statement inside a loop?

Answer (score 0):

just put `System.out.println ("more then 0 and less then 10 = "+count);`out of your looping code when reading the lines in the file. For example:

```
......
Looping...
do count++ if avg >=0 && avg<10;
End Loop..

print it by System.out.println ("more then 0 and less then 10 = "+count);
```

Hope it helps and answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

let me try and help u by listing some of the steps for ur problem.

First while scanning the numbers, put them into an array.
While ur putting the numbers in the array , sum it up. This will help u to give the sum result at the end of it.
After that take the average of the number by deviding with the array count.(This will help u save memory by preventing unnecessary variable creation.

After that use the array and if else logic to achieve ur end result.

**Also for the error that ur getting I guess ur printing it inside a loop.**